# How split columns based on another column postion in orcale sql

Tags: sql, oracle, split

I have a data set as below

Table name :  Data_table_1

| Customer_ID | Cus_activity | Cus_Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12985 | CURAC | 201 |
| 20917 | PINT$@CURAC$@CINT$@CURCM | 567$@291$@358$@434 |
| 548357 | CINT$@CURCM$@CURAC | 300$@934$@450 |
| 80315 | CURCM$@PINT$@CURAC$@CINT | 809$@345$@420$@567 |
| 234561 | CURAC$@CURCM$@PINT$@CINT | 500$@359$@200$@400 |

Output I need is as below

| Customer_ID | Cus_activity | Cus_Amount | CURAC_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12985 | CURAC | 201 | 201 |
| 20917 | PINT$@CURAC$@CINT$@CURCM | 567$@291$@358$@434 | 291 |
| 548357 | CINT$@CURCM$@CURAC | 300$@934$@450 | 450 |
| 80315 | CURCM$@PINT$@CURAC$@CINT | 809$@345$@420$@567 | 420 |
| 234561 | CURAC$@CURCM$@PINT$@CINT | 500$@359$@200$@400 | 500 |

The amount related to cus_activity capture in the Cus_Amount column
I need to get only the "CURAC" amount to a separate column

I tried as below but its incorrect

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(Cus_activity ,'[^CURAC]*$')
```

How to get it once from a large data set only the "CURAC" amount to a separate column?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option; basically, you'd split `cus_activity` and `cus_amount` to rows and then return only values that belong to `CURAC`.

```
SQL> with
  2  temp as
  3    (select
  4       customer_id, cus_activity, cus_amount,
  5       --
  6       rtrim(regexp_substr(cus_activity, '[^@]+', 1, column_value), '$') act,
  7       rtrim(regexp_substr(cus_amount, '[^@]+', 1, column_value), '$') amt
  8     from test cross join
  9       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 10                           connect by level <= regexp_count(cus_activity, '@') +1
 11                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 12    )
 13  select
 14    customer_id, cus_activity, cus_amount,
 15    max(case when act = 'CURAC' then amt end) curac_amount
 16  from temp
 17  group by customer_id, cus_activity, cus_amount
 18  order by customer_id;

CUSTOMER_ID CUS_ACTIVITY             CUS_AMOUNT         CURAC_AMOUNT
----------- ------------------------ ------------------ ------------------
      12985 CURAC                    201                201
      20917 PINT$@CURAC$@CINT$@CURCM 567$@291$@358$@434 291
      80315 CURCM$@PINT$@CURAC$@CINT 809$@345$@420$@567 420
     234561 CURAC$@CURCM$@PINT$@CINT 500$@359$@200$@400 500
     548357 CINT$@CURCM$@CURAC       300$@934$@450      450

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to split the rows (as that will be slow) and can find the position using simple string functions:

```sql
SELECT customer_id,
       cus_activity,
       cus_amount,
       SUBSTR(
         amt,
         INSTR(amt, '$@', 1, position) + 2,
         INSTR(amt, '$@', 1, position + 1) - INSTR(amt, '$@', 1, position) - 2
       ) AS curac_amount
FROM   (
  SELECT d.*,
         COALESCE((LENGTH(act) - LENGTH(REPLACE(act, '$@')))/2, 0) + 1
           AS position
  FROM   (
    SELECT d.*,
           SUBSTR(
             '$@' || cus_activity || '$@',
             1,
             INSTR('$@' || cus_activity || '$@', '$@CURAC$@') - 1
           ) AS act,
           CASE 
           WHEN INSTR('$@' || cus_activity || '$@', '$@CURAC$@') > 0
           THEN '$@' || cus_amount || '$@'
           END AS amt
    FROM   data_table_1 d
  ) d
)
```

If you did want to use a slower method of splitting the data into rows then, from Oracle 12, you can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   data_table_1 d
       LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL(
         SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(cus_amount || '$@', '(.*?)\$@', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1)
                  AS curac_amount
         FROM   DUAL
         WHERE  REGEXP_SUBSTR(cus_activity || '$@', '(.*?)\$@', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1)
                  = 'CURAC'
         CONNECT BY 
                LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(cus_activity || '$@', '(.*?)\$@')
       )
       ON (1 = 1)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE data_table_1 (Customer_ID, Cus_activity, Cus_Amount) AS
SELECT 12985,  'CURAC',                      '201'                FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 20917,  'PINT$@CURAC$@CINT$@CURCM',   '567$@291$@358$@434' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 548357, 'CINT$@CURCM$@CURAC',         '300$@934$@450'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 80315,  'CURCM$@PINT$@CURAC$@CINT',   '809$@345$@420$@567' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 234561, 'CURAC$@CURCM$@PINT$@CINT',   '500$@359$@200$@400' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 234562, 'NOCURAC$@CURCM$@PINT$@CINT', '500$@359$@200$@400' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | CUSTOMER_ID | CUS_ACTIVITY | CUS_AMOUNT | CURAC_AMOUNT |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 12985 | CURAC | 201 | 201 |
> | 20917 | PINT$@CURAC$@CINT$@CURCM | 567$@291$@358$@434 | 291 |
> | 548357 | CINT$@CURCM$@CURAC | 300$@934$@450 | 450 |
> | 80315 | CURCM$@PINT$@CURAC$@CINT | 809$@345$@420$@567 | 420 |
> | 234561 | CURAC$@CURCM$@PINT$@CINT | 500$@359$@200$@400 | 500 |
> | 234562 | NOCURAC$@CURCM$@PINT$@CINT | 500$@359$@200$@400 | *null* |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e2faa426fc2cd56fdefdff9f3a096ac7)*